# Automate provisioning of sharepoint, biztalk like cots products to azure using terraform

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-virtual-machine, terraform

- Is it possible to automate provisioning of sharepoint, biztalk like
  cots products to azure using terraform?
- If yes, how licensing would be handled?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is possible. How do you create this on Azure Portal? You just need find the image sku and publisher.

Comment: You mean market place image?

Comment: Yes, I mean this. Sharepoint is possible on Azure, you only modify the sku. Like this https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/11016504-support-msdn-images-sharepoint-sql-server-bizta

Comment: "storageProfile": { 
"imageReference": { 
"publisher": "MicrosoftSharePoint", 
"offer": "MicrosoftSharePointServer", 
"sku": "2013", 
"version": "latest" 
}

Comment: `biztalk`, do you mean biztalk service?

Comment: Yes, biztalk service....Also for sharepoint, whether same MSDN license of Azure account will be used for licensing?

Comment: Hi, if my understanding is right, you want to select a VM that sharepoint and biztalk server install on it? Sorry I am not very good at sharepoint and biztalk.

Comment: Not exactly...I am doing all provisioning through Terraform template   including VM creation, Executing some bootstrap script on it etc... Also along with VM creation, I want to create some services too like Sharepoint, Biztalk etc...So after terraform execution, I got a VM with all my needed services...e.g. I use "resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {......}" inside a template for making a VM in azure using terraform. Same way what would I mention for my licencing details for sharepoint, biztalk etc...I hope I didn't make things complex :)

Comment: If you have this script, you could use Azure Custom script to do this, but I think it will be complicated. Also, it seems you need prepare multiple VMs.

Comment: According to your scenario, I think you need prepare these licences.

Comment: Thanks. So what I am getting here is that once you logged inside azure, Terraform itself isn't checking any of your licenses, Azure will check though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166215/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-jaish-mathews).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to automate provisioning of sharepoint, biztalk like
>   cots products to azure using terraform?

Yes, it is possible. You could use [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) to do this.

But all software need support silent installation without user intervention.