# Connection timeout during file provision to azurerm vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting below timeout message once trying to provision file to an azure RM VM .

> unknown error Post
>   http://terraform.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:3389/wsman: read tcp
>   192.168.0.4:59745->52.224.162.240:3389: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I am trying file provision and the VM already there and no need to create it. I only need to copy a text file to an existing VM using below config.

```
provider "azurerm"
{
}
resource "null_resource" "test"
{

provisioner "file" 
{
        connection 
        {
            type = "winrm"
            user = ""
            password = ""
            host="terraform.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"
            port="3389"
            timeout = "20m"
        }
    source = "D:\\jaish\\output.txt"
    destination = "D:\\output.txt"

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check official document(Provisioner Connections) in this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html).

> Additional arguments only supported by the winrm connection type:
>
> https - Set to true to connect using HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Now, you use connection type is `winrm`, so you need open port 5986 on VM's firewall and Azure NSG. You also need create a self-signed certificate. You could check this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/) to do this.

---

Another solution, you could use [Azure Custom Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) to do this. You could create a script to download file from Azure Storage account or github.

Using terraform to do this, you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273561/unable-to-execute-custom-data-in-azure-vm-from-terraform).

Comment: Thanks...I am going to try this during weekend as now involved in some other stuff. I will update here for sure.

Comment: @JaishMathews OK, if you have any question about this, please update here.

Comment: Cool. I could able to run a PS1 script remotely using terraform. Only manual thing I done was after VM creation, installed Azure VM Agent in it. So now I have below 2 queries on terraform.                                                                   1. Can we refer an Azure VM Agent inside a .tf file, so that it would install along with vM creation?                                                                     2. Another one is an existing query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881795/automate-provisioning-of-sharepoint-biztalk-like-cots-products-to-azure-using-t

Comment: `1. Can we refer an Azure VM Agent inside a .tf file, so that it would install along with vM creation?`. Sorry I don't very understand it. Do you want to execute a script inside VM by using terraform, it is possible, you could use Azure Custom Script Extension.  If you want to use `winrm`, it will have a issue. By default, 5986 is not allowed on Windows Firewall.

Comment: Let me try to describe my query. Azure Custom Script Extension will download to an Azure VM by an agent called Azure VM Agent, by design. So this agent should run for Azure Custom Script Extension to download from Git/Storage and execute. Terraform script not installing this agent by default eventhough Azure portal will take care this if you create a VM from there.So I installed this agent manually after Terraform created my VM. Is there a way to mention this agent too inside Terraform template?

Comment: Do you mean you want to install Azure VM agent by terraform? In fact, this is not possible. By default, the agent is on the VM for marketplace image. If you use custom image, you need install it firstly.

Comment: OK. Got it. Related to this, I hope I could refer market place images or any distributed disk images in .VHD format inside Terraform template...

Comment: @JaishMathews You could prepare your image in local Hyper-V. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image#complete-recommended-configurations).

Comment: Ok, any link to refer an existing .vhd inside a Terraform template?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this approach before but the first thing that draws my attention is that you are using a type of winrm with a port of 3389.  3389 is used for RDP and the default winrm ports are 5985 (HTTP) and 5986 (HTTPS).

Comment: Seems a point here. Terraform does support SSH and WinRM and not mentioned about RDP. Let me try to enable SSH/WinRM in VM and will update here.