# Terraform - Copy Files to an existing Azure VM from Local

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform, winrm

This question has a Ref. to [Connection timeout during file provision to azurerm vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882420/connection-timeout-during-file-provision-to-azurerm-vm). I don't want to create a new VM, which already exists. I have WinRM activated in my VM for http and I could able to connect to VM through Powershell using http. But terraform not able to copy the file using below .tf with provisioner

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "D:/JAISH/TERRAFORM/output.txt"
    destination = "D:/jaish/output.txt"

    connection {
      type     = "winrm"
      user     = "uid"
      password = "pwd"
      host     = "IP"
      port     = "5985"
      timeout  = "20m"
    }
  }
}
```

It's always showing like below without any status change.

```
null_resource.test: Still creating... (18m21s elapsed)
null_resource.test: Still creating... (18m31s elapsed)
null_resource.test: Still creating... (18m41s elapsed)
null_resource.test: Still creating... (18m51s elapsed)
null_resource.test: Still creating... (19m1s elapsed)
null_resource.test: Still creating... (19m11s elapsed)
null_resource.test: Still creating... (19m21s elapsed)
```

Not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

WinRM is notoriously slow. Packer/Terraform use the same library to perform communication/file uploads via the WinRM protocol. Very slow. Try [archiving](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/archive/d/archive_file.html) the file first file before uploading to squeeze a bit more performance.

You can see an issue on Packers Github [here.](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/2648)

Comment: Strange ...I have a single .txt file with only my name written in it, 1 KB size. Nothing else...

Comment: That is strange. Make sure that no firewall rules etc are standing in your way?

Comment: I enabled debug log and got this message "connecting to remote shell using WinRM
2018-04-23T11:18:23.384+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform.exe: file-provisioner (internal) 2018/04/23 11:18:23 connection error: http response error: 401 - invalid content type
2018-04-23T11:18:23.384+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform.exe: file-provisioner (internal) 2018/04/23 11:18:23 Retryable error: http response error: 401 - invalid content type".....What's this content type meant by? I am trying to pass a .txt file

Comment: Have you got a proxy in between you and communication to the instance?

Comment: Resolved!!! I needed to manually enable below behaviors of WinRM connection inside my VM. After this file has been copied. winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled false"